# Angular Material Table with Firebase Is Empty

Tags: angular, firebase

Im trying to show some items from Firebase in an angular material table. I bring the items (cars) to an array and then I send that array in a dataSource, ut items are never shown. Here is my code:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.dbService.getCars().subscribe((cars) =>{
  this.cars.length = 0;
  cars.map((car:any)=>{
    this.cars.push(car.payload.doc.data());
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.cars);
  });

});
}
```

And getCars in the service:

```
getCars(){
return this.dbFirestore.collection('cars').snapshotChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing change detection after you update the data.

```
constructor(private changeRef : ChangeDetectorRef) { }

this.dbService.getCars().subscribe((cars) =>{
  this.cars.length = 0;
  cars.map((car:any)=>{
    this.cars.push(car.payload.doc.data());
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.cars);
  });

    //This line updates the UI with new changes in data
   this.changeRef.detectChanges();
});
```